# React native cannot read property '0' of undefine

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props

I'm new with ReactJS and today I have encountered a few problems.
I am currently using Redux to store my data and I was able to retrieve all the data from the props.

Ie.

```
const { recipe, loadingRDetail } = this.props;
console.log(recipe.macros);
```

recipe macros will show me 5 values in array.
[Array Image Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JnL0.png)

But when I tried to accessed to the array, It will throw me an error "**Cannot read property  '0' of undefined**".

I have tried

```
console.log(recipe.macros[0])
```

and

```
const {macros} = recipe;
macros.map((i) => {
    ....
}...
```

I have no luck with both of these

This is the error I get
[Red Warning error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSAVp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's just because your macros data is asynchronously loaded so you have to add a test to check if it's loaded.

You can try this:

```js
const {macros} = recipe;
if (macros && macros.length) {
  macros.map((i) => {
      ....
   }...
}
```

Or if you already are in your Render method you can just try this :

```js
const {macros} = recipe;
return (
  {
    macros && macros.length && /* It will check if macros has elements inside */
      macros.map((i) => {
          ....
       }...
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean now.
I have to set an initial value for macros and it will show.

Comment: Yes or you can add a test as i edited the code now ! to check if macros exists (actually it's to check if recipe is loaded and contain macros)